# How to use JMeter Plugin Prometheus Listener on server that isn't localhost

Tags: load, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use the JMeter Prometheus Plugin. All the guides set up the plugin to run on localhost.  Does anyone know how to override the option for localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/johrstrom/jmeter-prometheus-plugin#properties-you-can-override)

> **Properties you can override**
>
> - `prometheus.ip` - The ip the http server will bind to
> - `prometheus.port` - The port the http server will bind to

So it's sufficient to set these properties and the metrics will go to the remote Prometheus server.

The properties can be either set in *user.properties* file or passed via `-J` command line arguments

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)